# JBOSS/WILDFLY server on TLS/SSL using self-signed certificate without using the --ignore option or without bypassing the security?

Tags: curl, jboss, ssl-certificate, jboss7.x

I am trying to setup a API integration with a 3rd party which required SSL/TLS API endpoint.
I don't have much idea how this web-integration works.

This is how my jboss config file connector looks like:

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
            <ssl name="https" password="myPass" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/server.keystore"/>
</connector>
```

The certificate key file was generated using the following command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias jboss_certificate -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -keystore  server.keystore -storetype JKS
```

The request I am trying:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://<full_url>/hook
```

This is the error at integration endpoint:

```
    curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a certificate validation issue on the client and not an Wildfly issue. Your (self-signed) certificate is not valid and cURL is just letting you know that. If you want the client to trust this cert, then you need to add it to the client certificate store.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90450/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-list

If you need a (free) SSL/TLS certificate that is from a valid CA and your site is web-facing, you might try using https://letsencrypt.org to retrieve a valid certificate. Installing them into WFLY is not as seamless as it is for NGNX or Apache, but it can still be done in a few steps or scripted.